# History back() with fallback url

Tags: javascript

I've used this ( https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp ) to add a 'Continue Browsing' button on a thank-you page on my site.

I want to be able to send the user back 2 pages if they click the button, but if for some reason they filled in the form and didn't come from another page, then I wanted to add a fallback url, i.e. just the home page.

The button works, but is it possible to add a fallback url in the case there is no history?

This is my current code:

```
<button onclick="goBack()" class="et_pb_button">Continue Browsing</button>
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.go(-2);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This should be a good start https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

Comment: I think this only explains how to set it up, no fallback?

Answer (score 2):

You always check for the number of entries in the `History` object.

```
<button class="et_pb_button">Continue Browsing</button> 

<script> 
  var url = 'www.test.com/signin'; // you need to know where you want to redirect to before hand
  document.querySelector('.et_pb_button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(window.history.length > 2) {
          window.history.go(-2);
      } else {
         window.location.href = url;
      }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: So, would I amend to:
`<button onclick="goBack()" class="et_pb_button">Continue Browsing</button>
<script>
function goBack() {
if(window.history.length > 2) {
    window.history.go(-2);
} else {
window.location.href = "url";
}
</script>`

Comment: @BenBattaglia Also hit the check mark to accept this as an answer if this solves your issue.

Comment: This will fail to work in the user has a "forward" history, but no "back"history.